# How to serve files larger than 32 MB from GCS using GAE and Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I'm serving some files from GCS through a GAE application (using flask), recently I hit the 32 MB limit. It should according to the documentation be possible to serve files from GCS that are larger than 32 MB, but I can't find the correct python3 apis.

> [Response limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-handled) 
>   Dynamic responses are limited to 32MB. If a script handler generates a response larger than this limit, the server sends back an empty response with a 500 Internal Server Error status code. This limitation does not apply to responses that serve data from the Blobstore or Cloud Storage.

I've found the blobstore API which can serve files from GCS, but unfortunately that library is deprecated and not python3 compatible. This is what I think the code would have looked like in that approach

```
blobstore_filename = '/gs/{}/{}'.format(CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET, path)
blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)

response = Response("This should be overriden by App Enginge")
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
response.headers['X-AppEngine-BlobKey'] = blob_key
return response
```

I think in PHP there is a specific API method that does exactly what I need
[CloudStorageTools#serve](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.cloud_storage.CloudStorageTools#serve)

I've seen some suggestions for similar problems to use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) but that seems more like a work-around rather than an actual solution to the problem.

I had expected to find a method to serve content from GCS, I don't know if my search skills are failing me or the method I need doesn't exist for the python3 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a route on your app that returns a redirect to the GCS Signed URL.
This way you can control the access to the route, but the content itself is not served by your app.

Serving through your app will increase your cost and lower your performance, since a dynamic request is not cached by default and AppEngine instance time and egressing data are more expensive than serving from GCS.

The App Engine standard environments that have this feature, like PHP and Python 2, does this redirect internally, so the client do not see the access to GCS, but it is happening similarly.
None of the AppEngine specific APIs are available on Python 3 standard, [see here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#app_engine_apis).

In order to create a Signed URL on App Engine standard Python 3 you'll need to create a Service Account key manually. The Application Default Credentials provided on Compute Engine and App Engine cannot be used for digital signing. Python 2, Java, Go and PHP allow it because they use the internal App Identity API to generate the signature.

Although those are not available yet, Google's only remark on this till now that I have seen is:

> At this time, App Engine APIs are not available in the Python 3.7 runtime

So we can still have some hope.

Comment: I decided to try the signed url approach, the code seems fairly straight forward.
'
    # Create a Cloud Storage client.
    gcs = storage.Client()
    bucket = gcs.get_bucket(CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)

    blob = bucket.get_blob(path)
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(int(time.time() + 10))
    return redirect(url)
'

Comment: This whoever leads to an error
>AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html?highlight=authentication#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.

But is it obviously running as a service account, and from the examples I found online I shouldn't need to provide anything more while running on GAE. What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that the documentation says it doesn't work for Compute Engine (but does work for App Engine) makes me a bit worried about the fact that it says <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'>  in the error message.

Comment: The application default credentials cannot be used for digital signing. It is possible on App Engine standard for some languages because of the App Identity API. You need to use a manually managed service account key to create signed urls on Python 3. I added this to the answer in case anyone tries the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options in order to serve files:

1.-You can use a resumable uploads to upload objects to your [bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable).You only need to use the signed URL in the initial POST request.

2.-You can create a policy document (policy document defines what a user (with or without a Google account) can upload with a form POST, and provides authorization to ensure that the form can upload files into the target bucket) and use regular HTML forms to do the [upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable).

Please let me know your thoughts and how it goes.

Comment: I'm really only interested in serving files that I already have in a bucket, so GET not POST

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. This documentation [1] talks about getting an object from a bucket. You can take a look at it in order to verify if this is what you need,  you can  also use an HTML form to do the download.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object-download